# Getting "This webpage has a redirect loop" when permission denied

Tags: php, drupal

I'm working on a drupal site. Instead of showing a page with something regarding "permission not found" it just results in a redirect loop.

`"Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects."` - chrome error

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

EDIT: This happens when the user is logged in already and goes to a page that they do not have access to.

The problem is happening in the function login_register in user.module, where it breaks is the calls to drupal_get_form('user_login') and drupal_get_form('user_register'). In user_login the line that causes the redirect is: if ($user->uid) { drupal_goto(''); } In user_register, it's: if (!$admin && $user->uid) { drupal_goto('user/'. $user->uid); } When I comment those drupal_goto lines out, the page shows correctly.

It however shows the log in screen which I don't want. I want to be able to say "if the user is logged in but does not have permission to view this page, then show a message, otherwise if the user is not logged in, then show the login form"

Comment: Do you have the Spaces OG model on your drupal system?

Comment: check the code, there are infinite redirection

Comment: @Gaurav: where should I even start looking? I understand that there is infinite redirection but I don't know why or where I should even look.

Comment: Maybe it is redirecting to its self only to see that there are no permissions, and redirected to self again only to be stoped by the browser? Maybe there is a referrer variable you are not setting?

Comment: Are you using any values on the '/admin/settings/error-reporting' form? For example, if your 403/404 pages are set to go to 'node/123', please make sure node # 123 is published and anonymous/authenticated users are allowed to access a node of that type.

Comment: I went to that page. Default 403 (access denied) page: mysite/user/loginregister/
Default 404 (not found) page: (nothing)
Error reporting: Write errors to the log

See comment under first answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Check to see what your 403 error page is set to here: admin/settings/error-reporting .  If it's empty and nothing looks out of the norm.
- Switch your theme to Garland to rule out the problem being in your theme.

If those don't expose the cause of the problem, then start to isolate the problem by disabling modules.  The purpose of this is to isolate which module is causing the problem.

1) Make a backup of your database so you can easily get back to where you started,

2) Go to town disabling modules 1 by one. Start with custom modules and modules you've installed most recently, and then on to modules that may deal with access.  After that, just guess.

If you find a module causing the problem, then check to see if there's an update for it, or look in the project issue queue to see if it's a reported problem.  Otherwise, report it.

Good luck.

Comment: It doesn't happen on a specific URL it happens any time the user tries to access a page they don't have permission to.

Comment: It seems to be something wrong with the custom 403 page because I set that to nothing and it gave me the message "Access denied
You are not authorized to access this page. "

I'm still not sure what to look for on this page, but I'll keep trying

Comment: The custom page is the function login_register in user.module, where it breaks is the calls to drupal_get_form('user_login') and drupal_get_form('user_register'). In user_login the line that causes the redirect is: 
`if ($user->uid) {
    drupal_goto('');
  }`

In user_register, it's:
`if (!$admin && $user->uid) {
    drupal_goto('user/'. $user->uid);
  }`

When I comment those drupal_goto lines out, the page shows correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would trace HTTP headers to check the contents of the requests. Zend debugger could help also.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Setting breakpoints with Zend Debugger and checking the variables states.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the "permission not found" is viewable by all (i.e. also viewers that are not logged in and have no roles/rights/permissions whatsoever).

That is, probably the "permission not found" page can currently not be viewed without having certain permissions. Thus, the user is not allowed to view the "permission not found" page and gets redirected to the "permission not found" page, which again redirects to the "permission not found" page etc etc.

Comment: It is viewable by all... when you're not logged in it takes you to the page with no problem. When you are logged in it results in the redirect. The 403 page is  mysite/user/loginregister/

Comment: Have a look at the Apache Rewritelogs. They can be set in the .htaccess with RewriteLog "filename"; and RewriteLogLevel 9; See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog for more information.

Comment: It's not set in my htaccess file

Comment: Set it, and then check the log files. That gives you the full flow of how pages are redirected and why; very helpful!

Comment: I already know why... I need to know how to fix it. See my comments in the first answer by Coder1.

Comment: Well, it looks like  if ($user->uid) { drupal_goto(''); } could be a problem if the '' page again is a page that requires login. I would find out what that line is supposed to do, and if it is not important, just comment it out :-)

Comment: The page that is trying to go to requires you to me logged in but the user is already logged in. They just don't have permission to view the page they are being redirect to.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the access to the 403 page is denied. That will send you to the 403 page every time you try to visit the 403 page, ending in an infinite loop.

Comment: the 403 page is set to  mysite/user/loginregister/